# Adding .NET 4.5.0 EF6 Class Library as a reference to ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know there are tons of threads on this topic, but I have spent hours on my particular case and have yet to come up with a solution. The switch from dnx has confused things, as very little of what worked back then is now relevant.

I am trying to add my existing Entity Framework 6 class library project, which is targeting .NET 4.5.0, as a reference in my ASP.NET 5 project. I can't find the particular combination of platforms to target to get this thing to work. I just don't quite understand all the intricacies of how this new awful json system works.

I am receiving various errors. With the current project file listed below, it simply will not let me add the reference to the ASP.NET project. I have tried to upgrade my EF project to 4.6.1, then targeted both netcoreapp1.0 and net461 in the ASP.NET app while adding the NETCore.App as a dependency to netcoreapp, but this causes the server to return a 400 error with no exception or reason whatsoever.

There is also no "Google Chrome" option at the top like there normally is for debugging. The only values are "IIS Express" and the name of my project, neither of which goes into debugging mode, but just launches the site. There is no stop button afterward.

Here is my project.json:

```
  "frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},


"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.301",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1"  },
```

Comment: Dumb question, but why aren't you using EF core? It's designed to work with Asp.Net core. By adding a ref to EF6, you are defeating the whole purpose of having a Core app as you will introduce the .net dependency.

Comment: Because we already have an existing app that we are trying to phase out by building a new ASP.NET Core app alongside the old one while sharing the Model project. For many reasons, we are not yet ready to up and move to EF7, much as I wish we could!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and below works for me.

The Target platform for EF6.0 ClassLibrary project is .Net 4.6.1

In the project.json file Add the following to the frameworks section.

So that the framework section will be ;

```
"frameworks": {

  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
        "type": "platform"
      }
    }
  },
  "net461": {}
}
```

If you have

`"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
        "type": "platform"
      }`

in the main dependencies section remove it from the main dependencies to avoid duplicate entry issue.

**But in the provided project.json you don't have that block under main dependencies section. So the issue must be resolved by just fixing the frameworks section.**

Restore packages. Clean the solution and rebuild it. Then try to add the ClassLibrary project and it worked for me.

[This Article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/06/16/asp-net-core-rc2-error-nu1002-the-dependency-system-runtime-loader-4-0-0-rc2-24027-does-not-support-framework-netframeworkversionv4-6-1/) helped to figure out the root cause.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve my issue. It allows me to add the reference fine, but then when doing "dotnet restore" in the developer cmd prompt, I get the message "error: Unable to resolve 'Model' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'". Rebuilding works, but the site returns a 400 error. Every project in my solution aside from my ASP.NET app is now 4.6.1. I even added the dnxcore50 line, which I was led to believe we are not supposed to use anymore. I'll take any solution at this point!

Comment: There is also no "Google Chrome" option at the top like there normally is for debugging. The only values are "IIS Express" and the name of my project, neither of which goes into debugging mode, but just launches the site. There is no stop button afterward.